# Convert array buffer to blob and display as image in react and node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, blob, arraybuffer

I have created a react application which stores images as blob(bytea) in my postgresql database.
Now I want to load these images back to my application and display them as images. But if I load them back to my application they will be fetched as array buffer. As far as I understood I need to convert the array buffer back to blob and display the blob as an image in my application. Unfortunately I have no clou how to do this. So I ask for your support.

```
  const loadProfilepicture = async () => {
    let res = await getProfilePictureByUserID(token, match.params.user_id);
    setProfilepicture(res.data);
    console.log(res.data);
  };
```

```
export const getProfilePictureByUserID = async (token, user_id) =>
  await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/profilepicture/${user_id}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `${token}`,
    },
  });
```

This is how the data looks like
[image]

**UPDATE/SOLUTION**

I solved the issue doing the encoding within the database like so:

```
SELECT encode(profilepicture_image, 'base64') as data FROM profilepictures WHERE user_id = $1
```

Comment: Why not serve the `bytea` data as an actual image so you can simply use `<img src="/profilepicture/:userId">`?

Comment: For profile picture, using the url might work but maybe it's a private image with some sensitive data that might not have to be accessible just by using the url on the backend.